# what is the difference between operator on `Tensor` and `Tesnor.data` in the Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

what is the difference between operator on `Tensor` and `Tesnor.data` in the Pytorch?

For example,

```
import torch

a = torch.ones(2,2)
a = a + 1

b = torch.ones(2,2)
b.data = b.data + 1

print(a,b)
```

It seems that `a` and `b` gives me the same results. My equation is that what is the difference between `a` and `b`?

Comment: `.data` is there for backwards compatibility with the old `Variable`. You shouldn't use it anymore and just use `torch.Tensor` objects instead.

Answer (score 0):

Both are the same but
The `.data` field is an old field that is kept for backward compatibility but should not be used anymore as it’s usage is dangerous and can make computations wrong. You should use `.detach()` and/or with `torch.no_grad()` instead now.

you can verify with

```
a = torch.rand(3, 5)
type(a)                      #  torch.Tensor
type(a.data)              #  torch.Tensor
id(a)                          #  4493764504
id(a.data)                 #  4493475488
```